# How can I deploy a WAR in an embedded Jetty 8?

Tags: java, jetty, war

With the following code, how can I deploy a WAR application located on the classpath ?

```
private Server s; 

@BeforeClass
public static void setUp() throws Exception {
    // Start http server
    Random r = new Random();
    int port = 1024 + r.nextInt(8976);
    s = new Server(new InetSocketAddress("127.0.0.1", port));

    // Add my WAR for deployment here ...

    s.start();
}
```

**Jetty 8.0.1**
**JDK 6**

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Something like

```
    WebAppContext webapp = new WebAppContext();
    webapp.setContextPath("/");
    webapp.setWar(warURL);
    server.setHandler(webapp);
```

The war does not have to be on the class path.