# Is it possible to package into single war?

Tags: java, maven, web, package, war

I finished developing my web app and now after packaging it I get the following structure in output path:

[image: folders]

Is it possible to package **all these folders and files** into a single war file (like developers do it with **uber-jar** or **fat-jar**)?
I mean I just want a **single war** file in target folder as result of `maven-package` goal.

I also want my single war file being **executable** (on double-click), if it is possible.

Comment: your generated war already contains all needed files

Comment: Why do you want to bring test classes with your war?

Comment: What do you mean by executable war?

Comment: @korolar double click and it executes (like exe)

Comment: @AndrewTobilko So if I delete all these red folders my war-file still gonna work. Right?

Comment: @IngeniousTom, yes, consider it as an independent module which doesn't  have any dependencies with the outer world

Comment: @IngeniousTom: but war files are not supposed to execute themselves. They can only be "executed" by a JavaEE web container (JBoss, GlassFish, WebSphere, etc.).

Comment: @korolar OK you're right!

Comment: @AndrewTobilko thank you - you are right - I deleted all these red folders and even war.original - file it still executes. Thank you!

Comment: @IngeniousTom, I am not sure, but it seems they are created only as resources for `.war`packaging and you may configure their deletion after this operation.

Comment: @AndrewTobilko yes thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you just didn't understand the major idea of the `.war` packaging. You should consider it as an independent module which doesn't have any relations with the outer world. Therefore, you could use it on different systems and with different web containers (as has been mentioned in the comments, they are *JBoss*, *GlassFish*, *WebSphere*).

All this brings the following [advantages](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WAR_(file_format)#Advantages_of_WAR_files):

- Easy testing and deployment of web applications;
- Easy identification of the version of the deployed application;
- All Java EE containers support WAR files;
- MVC Structure also support WAR files.

Comment: Ok I understood. But what if my web app has embedded server like jetty? How can I deploy or install my war on target machine?

Comment: @IngeniousTom, I haven't done it before, but I found [this pretty answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9807291/how-can-i-deploy-a-war-in-an-embedded-jetty-8) for you.

Answer (score 1):

I have no guess why do you want to make the entire target directory into single war file.

> **1)** Is it possible to package all these folders and files into a single
>   war file (like developers do it with uber-jar or fat-jar)? I mean I
>   just want a single war file in target folder as result of
>   maven-package goal.

In case of any need, modify the `maven-package` phase configuration in the pom.xml and add all the files/directories to be packaged itself in the WebARchive (WAR).

But you don't need the directories/files (**except the WAR file which contains necessary classes, libs and resources**) in target directory anymore after maven package phase has been executed. If so, then add following **maven snippet** in your project's pom file and modify the configuration section according to your need.

**maven-snippet**

```
<plugin>
  <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
  <artifactId>maven-antrun-plugin</artifactId>
  <version>1.8</version>
  <executions>
   <execution>
     <id>id.post-clean</id>
     <phase>post-clean</phase>
     <goals>
        <goal>run</goal>
     </goals>
     <configuration>
        <target>
          <delete 
            dir="${project.build.outputDirectory}/dir-to-be-deleted"
            includeemptydirs="true"/>
        </target>
     </configuration>
   </execution>
  </executions>
</plugin>
```

> **2)** I also want my single war file being executable (on double-click), if
>   it is possible.

Yes it is possible. Before that you should know, WAR files are intended to wrap-up the application as an archive for web containers such as Tomcat, Glassfish, Weblogic, JBoss etc., It should be deployed via such containers for ease of access and configuring the application to avoid unexpected results in the runtime.

Making an WAR file executable by embedding any one container which is above mentioned and suites for your need. But it should not exactly as like windows or executable jar behaves.

Firstly, The war file should be invoked via java command in cli and then access the application via web browser or any http client.

[Here](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/create-a-java-web-application-using-embedded-tomcat) is an amazing article which provides guidance to embed apache tomcat app server into a java application.

Hope this could help you for achieving you goal.